# python docker-py client is newer than server

Tags: dockerpy

I want to run docker from python 3.6.3. The command from the terminal (Ubuntu) works fine, but my python script:

```
import sys
import docker
image = "blang/latex"

client = docker.from_env()
client.containers.run(image,  '-v /home/data blang/latex pdflatex main.tex', True)
```

returns:

> APIError: 400 Client Error: Bad Request ("client is newer than server (client API version: 1.30, server API version: 1.24)")

**docker-machine and docker versions**

```
docker-machine -v
```

> docker-machine version 0.13.0, build 9ba6da9

```
docker version
```

> Client:
>   Version:      1.12.6
>   API version:  1.24
>   Go version:   go1.7.4
>   Git commit:   78d1802
>   Built:        Tue Mar 14 09:47:15 2017
>   OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
>
> Server:
>   Version:      1.12.6
>   API version:  1.24
>   Go version:   go1.7.4
>   Git commit:   78d1802
>   Built:        Tue Mar 14 09:47:15 2017
>   OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Answer (score 1):

Check what is the version in your 'DOCKER_API_VERSION' environment variable if present. You can set it in order to match the server version.

Alternatively you can create a client manually not requiring any environment variable:

```
client = docker.DockerClient(base_url='unix://var/run/docker.sock', version="1.24")
```